# Is the author of Deadman Wonderland also the author of Smokin Parade?

Tags: deadman-wonderland, smokin-parade

The newly released manga *Smokin Parade* is said to be very similar to *Deadman Wonderland*. Are the authors the same or related in some way?

Comment: did you even [google?](https://www.google.com/search?q=deadman+wonderland+smokin+parade)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Smokin Parade does have the same authors as Deadman Wonderland. Both manga are written by Kazuma Kondou and illustrated by Jinsei Kataoka.